# Is it possible to load multiple excel file with many sheets into one masterfile

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got list of xls file :

```
   ['720000000109_000.xls',
 '720000000115_000.xls',
 '720000000117_000.xls',
 '720000000119_000.xls',
 '720000000204_000.xls',
 '720000000763_000.xls',
 '720000000792_000.xls',
 '720000002745_000.xls',
 '720000003277_000.xls',
 '720000006803_000.xls',
 '720000008076_000.xls',
 '720000008342_000.xls',
 '720000013082_000.xls',
 '720000016663_000.xls',]
```

Every single file include 2-10 sheets with same headers but different values
I've tried using pandas move it to DataFrame but it didnt work for me,this is output i get :

```
{'FOODS-TH': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [720000006803/000, 200000212338/000/000, FOODS:TH, Thai, CUC-ING, CUST-SST00007873, STORAGE, วิธีการเก็บรักษา: ปิดถุงให้แน่นทุกครั้งหลังใช้งาน ควรเก็บในที่แห้งและอุณหภูมิปกติ]
 Index: [],
 'PUBLIC-GCEA': Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [720000006803/000, 200000212338/000/000, PUBLIC:GCEA, English, CUC-ING, CUST-SST00002615, STORAGE, Store in a clean, cool and dry place.]
 Index: []}
```

Its dictionary now with key - sheet names, and i need output like this :

[image]

Comment: if you're not doing any data changes, openpyxl may be a better choice for this

Comment: is your data just the column names? it seems there is no actual data just a header row

Comment: No, this is what i showed its actually data , i skipped header row but if it help i can edit post and add it